# Madden 16 Defense Can't adjust camera zoom

Tags: madden-16

I am having the problem where the d pad is not allowing me to zoom in and out. This is really frustrating as I can't read the offense. Strangely, I can zoom in and out just find on special teams.

Thanks

Comment: Don't think I've had that happen before. Is this the first time it happened to you, or is it an ongoing problem? Were you in the player-lock camera? What, if anything, did you try to solve the problem?

Comment: @DCShannon How do I get out of player lock? I see that there is a lock under my character but pressing l3 doesn't help

Comment: You accepted my answer, but didn't upvote. Did you try either or both of the solutions? Did one of them work?

Comment: @DCShannon I tried both and they worked, thanks. I tried up-voting but it didn't let me. I forgot about it, oops. It was a few hours ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've accidentally activated the player lock camera, and can't get back out of it.

This has happened to a lot of people. I found many forum discussions about it, most with no resolution. Clicking the left stick (L3) enters the camera. Some are saying that it's R3. Quite a few people claim that you can toggle back out of it by simply pressing the button again.  This doesn't always work though. I recall having issues with it myself.

I did find a few suggested solutions:

> [1.](http://www.thecoli.com/threads/need-help-on-madden-16-how-in-the-hell.352867/) I did it but it's staying on lock player, whatever I switch the player and it's still on lock player.
>
> edited: I got it....had to turn the camera toggle off
>
> [2.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Madden/comments/3i398f/defensive_camera_player_lock/) In your game settings, go down till you see offensive and defensive camera options. Scroll on the defensive until you hit "standard". Hope this helps

You can find both of these solutions in your game settings. This video shows both of them being changed: